# How do I remove file extensions from a URLs of a GitHub Pages site (Jekyll) while keeping my HTML files in one folder?

Tags: url-rewriting, jekyll, github-pages

Is there a way to configure my files such that I can have the following folder structure map to the following URL structure?

```
/
    index.html    -> www.site.com
    about.html    -> www.site.com/about
    contact.html  -> www.site.com/contact
```

This is a very simple site with just a few pages so it'd be a nice way for me to keep the folder structure very clean and simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `about.html` use the following permalink

```
---
title: My about title
permalink: /about/
---
```

And in `contact.html`:

```
---
title: My contact title
permalink: /contact/
---
```

To remove trailing slashes you need to [configure the web server](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/#extensionless-permalinks)

Then you can create links hardcoding the URL or using the `link` tag:

```
[Link to a page]({{ site.baseurl }}{% link about.html %})
#Or
<a href="/about/">About</a>
```

Another way is to create the following file structure:

```
├── index.html
├── about
│   └── index.html
└── contact
      └── index.html
```

Then be sure your permalinks do not include the .html extension in _configu.yml and it will automatically generate the URLs.

Comment: What about for the index? If I type "myurl.com/index.html" it doesn't redirect to "myurl.com," it keeps the file extension.

Comment: @user3277733 based on this answer, I'd say try doing `permalink: /` in the front matter on your main `index.html` page.

Comment: @MichaelEdelstone that seems to just put the page in an infinite loading/refresh loop like it's trying to non-stop redirect itself to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `_config.yml` file:

```
permalink: /:title/
```

This will allow you to add a title to the frontmatter of posts/pages. The fallback for this is the filename, sans file extension.

For more:

https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/

http://jekyll.tips/jekyll-casts/permalinks/

Comment: This looks like what I want, but how would I link to the file in my anchor tag?

Comment: I tend to use just just the link. In the case of your www.site.com/about example I'd use `<a href="/about/">About</a>`. You could use `<a href="{{ site.url }}/about/">About</a>` if you wanted the whole URL included.